# iCal keeps re-enabling alarms

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, google-calendar, calendar.app

I have iCal synced with a google calendar account. I only have one calendar. When I disable an alarm for an event, a few seconds later the alarm keeps turning back on. This happens for all of the events I've already added. I've tried re-adding the account in iCal, same thing happens. I'm thinking it keeps syncing the alarm from google calendar and never pushes the updates to google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing seems to have started happening to me as well, recently.  It's on both my Leopard and Snow Leopard macs.

If I turn the alarms off either on my iPhone (push synced to Google via Exchange) or the google website they go away in iCal as well.

Comment: Just figured it out! Login to your google account on the website, then go into your calendar there. Now, select the "settings" next to the name of your calendar on the left sidebar.  Then click "notifications" in the list that appears.  If it says "by default remind me..." click the small "remove" link at the end. Then be sure to hit "save."  Worked for me!